Is a correction for sphericity violation needed for post-hoc comparisons following repeated-measures ANOVA?
In a repeated-measures ANOVA, there is an assumption of sphericity, so that the variance of differences between groups is similar for all pairs of groups. A violation of this assumption can be corrected by modifying the degrees of freedom used for the F-test, using either the Greenhouse–Geisser or Huynh-Feldt corrections. My question is, in subsequent post-hoc comparisons of pairs of groups, do the degrees of freedom also require modification? How would one do this?
Many thanks for your help.
A relevant reference on repeated measures and sphericity: https://statistics.laerd.com/statistical-guides/sphericity-statistical-guide.php

I would say that the best correction is to switch to a better method, such as multllevel models or generalized estimating equations.

Thanks for your reply @Peter. So, I'm actually fitting a multi-level model. But, I would like to get pairwise comparisons for all possible levels of the (single, categorical) fixed effect. The only method I have so far been able to discover, is to take the fitted mixed effects model object, and run it through an ANOVA and post-hoc tests. It does seem a round-about approach I concede. Is there a better way to obtain all the pairwise comparisons, having first fitted a mixed effects model?

I see no reason it shouldn't be possible, but exactly how to do it would depend on software and questions about code are off topic here. But look up "contrasts" in whatever program you are using.

One way to do this is to take you fitted mixed effects model and stick it into emmeans.

Thanks Peter and Stefan, I will take a further look at that. Can I clarify, are you saying that mixed effects models don't assume sphericity, so there's no need to make a correction for it? Or rather that a correction is required and is typically available in, e.g., contrasts functions and in emmeans? If it's the first, that would explain my misunderstanding, and why I wasn't able to get a sphericity correction out of emmeans with my GLMM object in the first place.

After some more reading around, this issue is addressed in a document by Paulo Gentil
The Greenhouse–Geisser correction for a sphericity violation modifies the degrees of freedom in the ANOVA. That modified degrees of freedom (see p 9 in that document) is then carried into subsequent posthoc comparisons (for example Tukey HSD, worked through on page 20-23) as a modified mean square error term. Paulo's document is written with reference to SPSS. Thank you Paulo if you are out there somewhere!
Edit: In the comments I also asked for clarification about whether spericity is an assumption of mixed effects models; and have since realised that Peter has addressed that question here. In short, sphericity is not an assumption of mixed effects models (the linked post considers LMMs). Which goes a long way to explaining why I couldn't get various R packages to supply a sphericity correction to my model object; it didn't need one. Thanks very much Peter and Stefan for your help.
